# Wanted: WinAPI calls logger

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, apimonitor

There was an "API Monitor" program, but it seems discontinued. Doesn't work on my system.
Is there any such tool, which can work on Windows 7 x64?
I need to log API calls from a selected set, better when parameter values.

Comment: Is "API Monitor" different than this program: http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor ?

Comment: See also [(Windows) Monitoring API calls in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720317/windows-monitoring-api-calls-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

I use the API Monitor tool at http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor.  It's not abandoned, the author seems to be releasing regular updates including some from the past year.  I found it relatively easy to learn, and have used it to discover API calls made by some components of Windows that I was studying, among other debugging tasks.

Comment: It has both 32 and 64 bit support.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), free from Microsoft, it's a library to hook the windows API, but it's not a complete monitor program, you have to do some work to intercept the API calls.

Comment: +1 for Detours in principle, it is an impressive and powerful library. As such it likely won't constitute the *API Monitor program* @skevar7 is asking for though, but you can certainly built one with it. The major issue though is that the free Express version works with 32-bit code only, for 64-bit code (as requested) you'll need the professional one, which is available for a *One-time licensing fee* of 'just' [$10,000](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/IntellectualProperty/IPLicensing/Programs/Detours.aspx) ...

Comment: @Steffen Opel  Wow, thanks for the heads up, that will certainly put a damper on the library, as more folks go to win64 dev.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bladeapimonitor.com/ seems to be doing what you need.

Depending on what you want to see, [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) might also do the job.

Comment: This blade monitor looks like a fake. Multiple typos in interface, and I can't get it working.