# Custom error logging from WinAPI calls in shared code

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have C++ code in Visual Studio that calls some functions from the Windows API. This code is shared and I don't want to change it much, but I want to provide error logging if some Windows function returns an error. My plan was to define alternatives to all Windows functions in a separate source file in some namespace `WinLog`, and force the shared code to call my functions instead of the Windows API functions. All of the shared code includes the `stdafx.h` header, and if I add these lines in that header:

```
#include "WinLog.h"
using namespace WinLog;
```

then the shared code would call my functions. I don't care about `using namespace` in header files. But the problem is that, now the compiler reports compilation errors, for instance:

> C2668: 'SCardReleaseContext': ambiguous call to overloaded function

How can I make the shared code call my functions if I only change something in `stdafx.h`?

Comment: Rather than *wrapping* the API functions, requiring callers to call your functions directly instead of the original functions, have you considered *hooking* the API functions instead? Most Win32 API functions can be detoured, such as with the [MSDetours library](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours). That way, when callers call the original API functions, your functions will be called instead.

Comment: *"How can I make the shared code call my functions"* - Compile your shim functions into a library and have the shared code link against your library rather than the exports from the Windows API.

Comment: Background information: [Understanding the classical model for linking: You can override an LIB with another LIB, and a LIB with an OBJ, but you can’t override an OBJ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130109-00/?p=5613).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825960/wanted-winapi-calls-logger

Comment: [(Windows) Monitoring API calls in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720317/)

Comment: Thanks all. I'll try Rohitab's API Monitor. Seems old, but functional and easy to use. And I don't have to recompile anything.

Comment: If you want to observe the behavior on your *local* system, you can use [Event Tracing for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/event-tracing-for-windows--etw-). If you need to debug an issue, but don't know exactly how/when/why it happens, [Time Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) is a nice option.